# Re-Rendering & Appending Child View's HTML to DOM Seems to Not Re-Apply Child View's Events

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In [the Marionette docs for `CompositeView`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md#compositeviews-appendhtml), it describes overriding `appendHTML` to customize the target the HTML of each `itemView` should be added to using jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Using a similar line of thinking, if I have two `ItemView` objects, a `Parent` and a `Child`, and `Parent`'s template has an empty target `<div class="target"></div>` I'd like to inject `Child`'s template inside of. I can use jQuery's [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with an `onRender` in `Parent` to do this.

Throughout the course of the `Parent`'s life, I want to flush out or replace the contents of `.target` with something else. If I later want to re-render `Child` into `.target` *(since it may render it's template differently based on user interaction since the first rendering)*, I can use the same logic:

1. Render the `Child` template
2. Set `.target`'s contents to `Child`'s `el` with jQuery's [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

The issue is, once this second rendering of `Child` has occurred, any events from the `Child` view seem to be lost.

Here is a concrete example of what I'm describing:

**The HTML**

```
<script type="template" id="parent">
  <p><a class="re-render" href="javascript://">Re-Render</a></p>

  <div class="target"></div>
</script>

<script type="template" id="child">
    <p><a href="javascript://">The Link</a></p>    
</script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

**The Javascript**

```
var Views = {};

Views.Child = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#child',

    events: {
      'click a': 'changeBg'
    },

    changeBg: function() {
       this.$el.css('background-color', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)); 
    }
});

Views.Parent = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#parent',

    childView: undefined,

    ui: {
      target: '.target'
    },

    events: {
      'click .re-render': 'onRender'
    },

    initialize: function() {
      this.childView = new Views.Child();  
    },

    onRender: function() {
      this.childView.render();
      this.ui.target.html(this.childView.el);
      this.childView.$el.css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});


var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
App.addRegions({
  mainRegion: "#main"
})


App.mainRegion.show(new Views.Parent());
```

Clicking **The Link** in `Child` at first works great. Once **Re-Render** is clicked in `Parent`, the `Child` click event is never re-applied to the newly rendered version of the `Child`'s template. **How can I ensure the `Child` template's events will be re-applied each time the `Child` is rendered?**

You can find a jsFiddle for this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/deefour/Hpmsw/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `.delegateEvents()` on the child view after it has been re-rendered:

```
onRender: function() {
  this.childView.render();
  this.ui.target.html(this.childView.el);
  this.childView.delegateEvents();
  this.childView.$el.css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```

This is how to solve it in vanilla Backbone. I don't know if Backbone.Marionette has another way of handling the problem, but in Marionette terms you could add the `delegateEvents` call to the child view's `onRender` method to encapsulate the re-renderability.

```
Views.Child = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    //...
    onRender: function() {
        this.delegateEvents();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks; that's exactly what I was looking for. Marionette overrides delegateEvents to add a bit of extra functionality to it's `View` implementation, but otherwise seems to let Backbone take care of `delegateEvents` as it normally would. Much appreciated.